# Is it possible to center align the data in a grid control?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to center align the data in a grid control? If so please help.

Comment: What technology are you talking about? WinForms? WPF? Can you provide an example of your code?

Comment: Hi.....Iam working with .net 3.5. I have numerical data to be displayed on the grid User_Count Task_Time etc., thanx :-)

Comment: Still not really clear whether you're using WinForms, ASP.NET, WPF...

Comment: dataTable3.Rows.Add("09:45 AM - 10:00 AM", 2, 1, 3);
            dataTable3.Rows.Add("12:00 PM - 12:15 PM", 2, 1, 3);           
            dataTable3.Rows.Add("12:45 PM - 01:00 PM", 2, 1, 3);


            GridView2.DataSource = dataTable3;
            GridView2.DataBind();

Is it possible to center align the column data. thanx pls help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" as property to your column in the grid view/ data grid.

Comment: ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign='Center" exactly solved my issue... thanx a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Define a Celltemplate with HorizontalAlignment="Center"

- Link:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.celltemplate.aspx

Comment: consider marking an answer as your accepted answer(the tick) or mark answer as useful(the arrow up) ;)

Regards,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

In your grid define

```
HorizontalAlignmnet = "Center"
```